# How can I install Lenovo Legion Y520-15IKBA's Amd Radeon RX graphics driver on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card

I'd like to run Windows 8.1 on it and I could while other drivers work fine, I cannot get the graphics driver to get installed. The installer fails with error 182 (can't properly recognize the hardware) and the device manager can't find drivers even after pointing it to the directory where the driver has been extracted to.
Also I'm not quite sure that it is an RX 460 or 560 GPU. People around the Internet say it is RX 560 while BunsenLabs 8.7 says it is RX 460 (according to the ID it displays after `lspci`). And the autodetect utility quits with another message, *There's nothing to install because every driver is installed and working*. Unfortunately this is not the case.
[Output of `lspci - v`](https://ghostbin.com/paste/v2q33) and [`lshw`](https://ghostbin.com/paste/z3k7e) on BunsenLabs 8.7 (Hydrogen).

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing the driver from AMD?

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following steps:

**First**, we need to confirm the device configuration of the Lenovo Legion Y520-15IKBA in Lenovo official website. 
**Second**, we confirm the model of the device graphics driver based on its device configuration.
**Third**, we download the corresponding device driver according to model of the device graphics driver in Lenovo official website.
**Forth**, we uninstall the original device driver if you have already installed, restart the computer and install the correct device driver.

Comment: I already downloaded the driver's installer from the laptop's official site but it quits with error 182. Removing the Microsoft Basic Display driver, it will be reinstalled upon reboot/running the AMD RX driver installer. Device manager does not find any driver this way either.